# how sliding image with page viewer position select manually?

Tags: android

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if(count== 1){
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[firstposition]);
        count++;
        position=firstposition;

    }
    else
    {
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    }

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more than a code snippet, i.e. what is your question (see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: as said by @zeeMonkeez please add code snippet(initialization of viewpager if used). So if you have used viewpager then try with  viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);